# Name of this kind of stain on fruits and how do they form

Tags: fruit, infectious-diseases

Last year I made some photos with avocados touched by some stains. They were even more delicious than the regular ones.

What's the name of such stains and how do they form? My guess is that they form because the fruit was hurt but maybe that's just me.

Later edit: A farmer told me it's a disease. Then I've found that it looks quite similar with apple scabs. Is it correct to call this "Avocado scab"? Is it made by the "Sphaceloma perseae" fungus?

Here are the photos:

[image: Imperfect Avocado - Stain1 A]
[image: Imperfect Avocado - Stain2 B]
[image: Imperfect Avocado - Stain3 A]

Answer (score -3):

You never visited the avocado blemish identification fanpage? do you use google? it's quite good.

http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/C008/m008fpfrtdmg.html
Causes of avocado Damage

Avocado thrips

Anthracnose

Caterpillars

Branch canker and dieback

Fruit and stem-end rots

Genetic mutations

Greenhouse thrips

Latania scale
Mechanical injury

Nutritional disorders

Off-season fruiting

Persea mite

Phytophthora fruit rot

Sooty mold

Sunblotch

Sunburn

Vertebrates

Weather extremes

Wildland fire

mosty they are insects, funghi, viruses, mechanical forces, and sometimes, like the woody avocado, the cause is unknown:
[image]
referenced.

Comment: Well, I guess each kind of damage looks different and distinct from the others, that's why I was asking what kind of specific damage is the one in the photos I referenced.